# Singularity point

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to study the nature of the point at infinity for this function f(z) = cotan(z) - (1/z) in complex analysis, i just do not know how to start is it about singular point nature or about the limit any help would be apreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: To study $f(z)$ near $z=\infty$, set $g(z) = f(1/z)$, and work with $g(z)$ near $z=0$.

Comment: It is a limit of poles so it is not isolated singularity